# Proof that a union of two non-regular languages may be regular

Tags: regular-languages

Let $L_1 = \{ a^{n}b^{m} \mid n > m > 0 \} $. Describe a non-regular language $L_2$ such that $L_3 = L_1 \cup L_2$ is regular and $L_3 ≠ A^{*}$ (where $A = \{ a, b \} $)

From the trace, I cannot prove this with the simple language of $L= \{ a^{n}b^{m} \mid n,m > 0 \} $ since it must be different from $A^{*}$.

I had thought of $L_2 = \{ a^{n}b^{m} \mid n ≤ m \} \setminus \{ aab \} $, so in this way we do not consider a string of $L_1$ and the union is different from $A^{*}$

Comment: Your choice of $L2$ looks good (but what are you trying to achieve with that ${}-\{aab\}$? After all $aab\notin\{\,a^nb^m\mid n\le m\,\}$) - where are you stuck?

Answer (score 6):

Let $L_2 = A^* \setminus (L_1\cup \{\varepsilon\})$. Then $L_1 \cup L_2 = A^*\setminus \{\varepsilon\}$ which is regular and not equal to $A^*$.

Comment: and is it equivalent to writing that $L3 = a^{n} b^{m} | n,m > 0 }$ since there is no empty string in $L1$ or $L2$? ($n,m> 0$)

Comment: No, because there is no obligations for $b$'s to necessarily follow $a$'s. For example, $baba$ is a word of $L_3$ in my case.

Comment: Right, I got confused. So it would have been correct to combine $L1 = ${$ a^{n} b^{m} | n > m > 0 $}$ $ with $L2 = ${$ a^{n}b^{m} | n <= m $}$ $
and get $L3 = ${$ a^{n} b^{m} | n,m > 0 $}$ $ which is regular?

Comment: If you meant $0 < n \leqslant m$ in $L_2$, then yes.

Comment: Yes I mean that, thank you now it is clear I was confused about the definition of A*

Comment: $A^*$ is the set of all words over letters of $A$.

Comment: How do we know $L_2$ is not regular?

Comment: It would have been nice to put that in the answer.

Answer (score 5):

Nowhere does the question state that the intersection of $L1$ and $L2$ must be empty.

Also for L1 to contain the empty string it must be that $m = n =0$ in the description, however $m,n >0$, therefore $L1$ doesn't contain the empty string.

The obvious solution is for $L3 = \{ a^*b^* \}$ (using kleene star) And then figuring out which non-regular language is a superset of $L3\setminus L1$.

Though technically saying $L2 = \{ a^*b^* \} \setminus L1$ is a sufficient solution assuming they can prove that it is non-regular (which you can do using the fact that intersection, complement and union operations are closed under regular languages). But it's simpler to simply take the $\{ a^{n}b^{m} | n <= m\}$ because that fills in all missing pairs of n and m that are missing from $L1$.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want $L_2$ to be the complement of $L_1$ (as then $L_3$ would the set of all words), then you can simply choose $L_2$ to be $\overline{L_1}\setminus L$, where $L$ is a nonempty finite language that is contained in $\overline{L_1}$.

Correctness follows from standard closure properties of regular languages, and from the fact that every finite language is regular. So you get in total that $$(\overline{L_1}\setminus L) \cup L = \overline{L_1}$$ Hence, since $L\in \text{REG}$ and $\overline{L_1}\notin \text{REG}$, we get from regular languages being closed under union that $\overline{L_1}\setminus L\notin \text{REG}$. Then, the union $(\overline{L_1}\setminus L) \cup L_1 = A^* \setminus L = \overline{L}$ is regular.

**Note:** In any problem where you are asked to come up with a regular or a non-regular language, then adding or subtracting a finite language from the answer won't change it as regular languages are closed under complementation, intersection (and hence difference -- think why) and union. This is useful in particular for this annoying edge cases where you get a correct answer up to a finite number of words.